# Fold expressions maximum number of elements in expansion pack

Tags: c++, c++17

Please consider the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t... I>
T sum_impl(T (&a)[N], std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
  return (a[I] + ...);
}

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
T sum(T (&a)[N])
{
  return sum_impl(a, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

int main()
{
    int a[512] = {[0 ... 511] = 1};
    std::cout << "Sum =" << sum(a) << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69e9cc6982dcd7ca)

In cases as the above, fold expressions are IMHO a good way to unfold what otherwise would have been a for loop. The questions that naturally arise are:

1. Is there a maximum number of elements in the expansion pack of the fold expression per vendor and how we can get/access this number (e.g., in VC++2017 for some reason the maximum number is 745, otherwise the program doesn't compile)?
2. Is there a number of elements in the expansion pack of the fold expression that if exceeded the performance is compromised. That is, is there a rule of thumb that if this number is exceeded it would have been better if we have used a for loop?

Comment: `int a[512] = {[0 ... 511] = 1};` is nonstandard.

Comment: Are you sure that the fold outperforms a normal loop, for any number? I'd expect the only difference to be compile time...

Comment: @Barry I’m quite confident for the opposite, and that’s what I’m asking in 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The specification of a fold expression in the C++ specification begins as follows:

> 8.1.6 Fold expressions                                                                                         [expr.prim.fold]
>
> A fold expression performs a fold of a template parameter pack
>   (17.5.3) over a binary operator...

It goes on for a couple of paragraphs. Nothing in them sets the minimum or a maximum size of a fold expression that a C++ compiler must support. This is unspecified, in this section of the C++ standard; so this is entirely up to the individual C++ implementation. There are no specified means for determining a particular compiler's limits. You've discovered that your particular compiler limits the fold expression to 745 values. The reason for that limit obviously has something to do with your compiler's internal implementation details; and without being familiar with them, there's not really much more that can be said about it. Other compilers' limits might be smaller or larger, or be limited only by the amount of available memory.

PS. Regarding the reference to the specification for a template parameter pack, that part of the C++ standard does not specify a minimum/maximum size of a parameter pack that a C++ compiler must support.

EDIT: It's been pointed out that Annex B lists some recommendation, but does not specify them as absolute requirements; and does not explicitly call out the maximum limits of a fold expression.

However, Annex B does call out:

> Template arguments in a template declaration [1 024].

One could argue that if this usage of "arguments" incorporates the arguments in a parameter pack, which will indirectly affect fold expressions.

Comment: You're better off looking in [Annex B](http://eel.is/c++draft/implimits) for implementation limits, though even those are only recommended minimums. There's nothing in there about fold expressions specifically from my quick skim.